# derivative logical meaning basic question

Tags: derivatives

The question is about the logical meaning of $\frac{df(x-1)}{dx}$, I did a single transform, which is $\frac{df(x-1)}{dx} = \frac{df(x-1)}{d(x-1)} * \frac{d(x-1)}{dx}$, since latter part $\frac{d(x-1)}{dx}$ is $1$, so $\frac{df(x-1)}{dx} = \frac{df(x-1)}{d(x-1)} = \frac{df(x)}{d(x)}$?

To me it seems $\frac{df(x-1)}{dx}$ is not the same as $\frac{df(x)}{d(x)}$? If anyone could explain the logical meaning of $\frac{df(x-1)}{dx}$ and how it equals to $\frac{df(x)}{d(x)}$, it will be great. :)

BTW, similarly, I can also get $\frac{df(1-x)}{dx}$ is $-\frac{df(x)}{dx}$

Please any steps is not correct, please feel free to correct me.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I think you have misapplied the chain rule in the first step. You should have $\frac{df(x-1)}{dx} = \frac{df}{d(x-1)} * \frac{d(x-1)}{dx}$

Comment: Thanks @BernardWojcik, vote up, I think your formula is the same as mine, what is the differences? I see there is an additional sign of `-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s look at the chain rule using a different notation, since I suspect that’s what’s tripping you up. It says that $$(f\circ u)'(a) = f'(u(a))\,u'(a).$$ Note that the derivative of $f$ is taken at $u(a)$. This is an important detail that in my opinion the Leibnitz notation obscures. (You can find a similar, but probably better-presented, explanation of the chain rule in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165484/265466).)

In your case, we have $u:\xi\mapsto \xi+1$, so $(f\circ u)'(x) = f'(x+1)\cdot1 = f'(x+1)$. This makes intuitive sense: $f\circ u$ is just $f$ shifted to the left by one unit, so one would expect $(f\circ u)'$ to be $f'$ shifted left by one as well.

Using Leibnitz notation, you started off well enough, but appear to have lost the fact that the derivative of $f$ must be taken at $x+1$. Keeping explicit track of where the derivatives are evaluated, we have $${df(\xi+1)\over d\xi}\Big|_{\xi=x} = {df(\xi+1)\over d(\xi+1)}\Big|_{\xi=x}{d(\xi+1)\over d\xi}\Big|_{\xi=x} = {df(\eta)\over d\eta}\Big|_{\eta=x+1}\cdot1\Big|_{\xi=1} = {df(\eta)\over d\eta}\Big|_{\eta=x+1}.$$ I’ve introduced some new variables to distinguish what are effectively dummy variables from the points at which the derivatives are evaluated. This is more or less te derivation you had, except that derivative of $f$ is evaluated at $x+1$ instead of at $x$. A similar derivation gives $${df(1-\xi)\over d\xi}\Big|_{\xi=x} = -{df(\eta)\over d\eta}\Big|_{\eta=1-x}$$ which is again what you had except evaluated at $1-x$.

As a concrete example, take $u:(\cdot)\mapsto(\cdot)+1$ again and let $f:(\cdot)\mapsto (\cdot)^3-2(\cdot)+1$. (Here I’m using $(\cdot)$ to stand for the function parameter so that there’s no chance of confusing it with the variables in the arguments to the functions.) The derivative of $f$ at any point is given by $f':(\cdot)\mapsto 3(\cdot)^2-2$ and the chain rule essentially tells us that we can find $(f\circ u)'(x)$ by plugging $u(x)=x+1$ into $f'$ (and multiplying by $u'(x)$, which is $1$ here). Doing so gives us $3(x+1)^2-2 = 3x^2+6x+1$. We check this by expanding $f(x+1)$ and differentiating the result: $$f(x+1)=(x+1)^3-2(x+1)+1=x^3+3x^2+x$$ and differentiating this yields $3x^2+6x+1$ again.

Comment: Thanks amd, vote up for your reply. What is the meaning of sign $\circ$ in $f \circ u$? Also lost in your formula $(f \circ u)' (x)$ means  $(f \circ u)' * (x)$

Comment: The $\circ$ stands for function composition: $f\circ u$ is the function defined by $f\circ u: \xi\mapsto f(u(\xi))$. The notation $(f\circ u)(x)$ means “evaluate $f\circ u$ at $x$.” Similarly, $(f\circ u)'(x)$ means “evaluate the derivative of $f\circ u$ at $x$.”

Comment: Thanks amd, vote up for your reply. Studied and learned a lot in your reply, and last question is, what is wrong in my original post (I mean if any steps I posted in original post is not correct in your mind)? :)

Comment: @LinMa The problem lies in the last step, when you substituted $x$ for $x+1$ in the derivative. That part itself is fine, but when you do that you have to remember to evaluate it at $x+1$.

Comment: Thanks amd, vote up for your comments. Do I should name $x+1$ or $x-1$ as another variable to reduce confusion, for example, $t=x+1$ and $s=x-1$? Then represent it as $\frac{df(t)}{dt}$ and $\frac{df(s)}{ds}$, correct? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa Yes, that would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks amd, mark your reply as answer. Sorry for the late response. Enjoy remaining time of weekend. :)